# Same Address shows two different locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-fusion-tables

So I am currently have a problem with google maps.  I am using a fusion table to populate a google maps `FusionTableLayer` via the `google maps js api V3`.  In my table I have a column with type "location" that is geocoded.  It all works, but my problem can easily be seen on the following map:

http://goo.gl/maps/Caon1

As you can see, the only difference in the addresses is the word "Dillards" added to the front of the destination address, and yet they are nearly a mile apart.  The address I am actually looking for is the destination address at Dillard's, but if I just put the address into google, it shows the source address.

The table has some 20k+ entries in it, and I need these geocode data to be correct for all of them.  Right now about 15% of them are incorrect like this one.  I don't mind re-geocoding the table, but it doesn't look like that's going to be a solution if Google is actually returning an improper latLng for an address.

Any suggestions on how I can make sure I get the correct latLng for addresses when geocoding?  I thought about adding the location name to the geocoding, but that returns even worse results.

---

**UPDATE**

It looks like my fusion layer is actually returning a third location.  I've added it to this map:

http://goo.gl/maps/KCG4F

It's not exactly on top of C, if you pan left a little, you will see a LensCrafters out in the middle of nowhere, and it's actually putting my marker directly on top of it.  Seriously Google Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entry on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) is coming from a Places entry, you can  get that result from the Places API or the Places library in the Google Maps API v3.  The Fusion Tables Geocode functionality doesn't use the Places database.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxB.html

enter: "Dillard's: Uptown Village, Cedar Hill, TX" in the text box.

Not sure how to automate the selection.  You may need to manually fix some of them.

Comment: Yah I'm thinking I may need to add another column to each of the results.  My hands are tied on some of the functionality, so they don't want to make another call to place markers, so using the Places API is out.